# Git: how to unignore all Symfony vendor files?

Tags: php, git, symfony, gitignore

unfortunately I **can't use composer**, due to low memory on the webspace. That's why I'm trying to push `vendor/*` to the git repository, to be able to pull the full project, including the dependencies.

In my `.gitignore` I'm forcing git to unignore the vendor files by `!/vendor/*`.

It **works for most files**, but not for `/vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle`.

Content of `/vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/.gitignore`:

```
/phpunit.xml
/composer.lock
/composer.phar
/vendor/
/node_modules/
```

My repository is hosted at BitBucket. I don't know yet the meaning of the **different folder-icon** and the hashs next to it. If anyone knows, please comment.

[image]

Does anyone know how to force git to handle all the vendor files?

Thanks in advance!

**Solutions**
As the `jsrouting-bundle` is a `git submodule`, I chose this solution:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle.git vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle
```

Another way would be to use the deps file (not tested), source:
https://github.com/XKEYGmbH/ifresco-client/tree/master/vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/FOS/JsRoutingBundle/Resources/doc

Comment: `git add` has a `--force` option. Have you tried that?

Comment: If you don't have spare memory for composer you should perhaps consider changing your hosting service.

Comment: @JonStirling I didn't know about the `--force`, thanks. But it only added other files, which are not interesting (`.idea/*`).

Comment: @tBureck Unfortunately that's not up to me, but I totally agree with you.

Comment: Why not upload the vendor directory manually?

Comment: @ShiraNai7 I'd like to avoid it and only work with git, but would have to do it in the worst case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jsrouting-bundle` folder is a [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). A Git submodule is actually a reference to another Git repository. This is why you cannot add changes from it to your original Git repository.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. I never heard about Git submodules.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this in the past, here is what I did:

- `php composer.phar selfupdate`
- `php composer.phar update`
- In the `vendor` directory run `sudo find . -type d -name .git | xargs rm -rf`
- Commit all modifications: `git add -A .`

With this, your vendor will be commit like the `src` directory, so no need to run `composer install` when deploying in your production environment. When wanting to update just repeat the process. But of course it isn't a good practice and you should do this only if you can't run `composer` on your production server.